# how I can draw this using tikz

Tags: tikz-pic

[image]

Please help me. How can I draw this using tikzpicture. Thank you.

Comment: That's a simple parametric plot, possibly with some `random steps` decoration if you want the irregularities.

Comment: yes. thanks.  I got it